# I need to let the user edit and update the data in gridview so that database data gets updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms

Here in my code i'm trying to let the user edit the gridview and hence update the database accordingly.The gridview is made on a webform page in aspx which shows the user data in tabular structure.But the problem is here that when i click on edit link of gridview it lets me to edit the data but when i update the gridview row,the associated event of onrowupdating doesn't gets called or fired at all.Even when i written all the code for it but still it's not working.What's the problem in this Please help me with this.Below is my whole code:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Welcome To My First Web Form<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Candidate Registration Form</h1>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Applicant&#39;s Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" EnableViewState="False" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Please enter Your Name!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Applicant's FName"></asp:Label>
            :&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Father name!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Gender"></asp:Label>:&nbsp;<asp:RadioButtonList ID="gender" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" Width="141px" RepeatLayout="Flow">
            <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="gender" ErrorMessage="Please Choose your Gender" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="E-mail ID"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;:&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox3_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="E-mail address is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            &nbsp;
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="E-mail addresses must be in the format of name@domain.xyz" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ForeColor="Red">Invalid Format</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="password"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;:&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Password is Required!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;:&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" ErrorMessage="The passwords Didn't Match!" ForeColor="Red" ControlToCompare="TextBox4" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CompareValidator>
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                 AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
                AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
                OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
                OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating1">
                <%--   <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Cname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Cfname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Cmail" />
            </Columns>--%>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <br />
 

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CS code file for this:-

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\App_Data\Candidates.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        public static int count = 0;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                gvbind();
                //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                //dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("FatherName"), new DataColumn("E-mail") });
                //ViewState["Candidates"] = dt;
                //GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["Candidates"];
                //GridView1.DataBind();
                
               
            }
        }
        protected void gvbind()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Candidates", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
        

        protected void TextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count += 1;
            int rowIndex = 0;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Candidates values('"+TextBox1.Text+"','"+TextBox2.Text+"','"+TextBox3.Text+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            
           
            //if (count > 1)
            //{
            //    DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Candidates"];
            //    DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            //    if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0) {
            //        //for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            //        //{
                        
            //            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            //            int totalrows = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count;
            //            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            //            dtCurrentTable.Rows[totalrows]["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
            //    dtCurrentTable.Rows[totalrows]["FatherName"] = TextBox2.Text;
            //    dtCurrentTable.Rows[totalrows]["E-mail"] = TextBox3.Text;
            //    rowIndex++;
                
            //        //}
                    
            //        ViewState["Candidates"] = dtCurrentTable;
            //        GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            //        GridView1.DataBind();
            //        TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            //        TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
            //        TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;
            //    }
            //}
            //else
            //{

            //    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Candidates"];
            //    dt.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), TextBox2.Text.Trim(), TextBox3.Text.Trim());
            //    ViewState["Candidates"] = dt;
            //    TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            //    TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
            //    TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;
            //    BindGrid();
            //}
            
            

        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        //protected void BindGrid()
        //{
        //    //GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["Candidates"];
        //    //GridView1.DataBind();
        //}
        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            gvbind();
        }
      
        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating1(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            Label lblID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblID");

            TextBox textName = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
            TextBox textFname = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
            TextBox texte = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
            ////TextBox textadd = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtadd");
            ////TextBox textc = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtc");
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Candidates set Cname='" + textName.Text + "',Cfname='" + textFname.Text + "',Cmail='" + texte.Text + "'where Cname='" + name + "'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            gvbind();
            //GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There should be edit and update button in the GridView. I can't see any of them. You aren't triggering them to do so.

Comment: @AT-2016 I have link labels which should serve the same purpose i think

Comment: Label is used to show text. It will not work actually for the editing purpose.

Comment: @AT-2016 sir i've already done that,by using autogenerate edit and autogenerate delete set to true in gridview properties.